# How to merge two data frames and pick lowest value from duplicated row in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames `x` and `y`:

```
> x <- data.frame(name = c("foo","bar"), c1 = c(0.1,0.2), c2=c("y","w"))
> x
  name  c1 c2
1  foo 0.1  y
2  bar 0.2  w
> y <- data.frame(name = c("foo","bar","qux"), c1 = c(0.3,0.2,0.8), c2=c("k","w","z"))
> y
  name  c1 c2
1  foo 0.3  k
2  bar 0.2  w
3  qux 0.8  z
```

In reality the column can be more than `c2`.
What I want to do is to merge them so that it result in this:

```
name c1 c2
foo 0.1 y
bar 0.2 w
qux 0.8 z
```

So note that when merging and when there are two rows with same `name` but different `c1` value
we pick one with lowest `c1`, regardless the value in `c2,c3,c4....` How can I achieve that?

I tried the command `merge(x,y,by='name')` but didn't work as I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unique.data.table has a `by` argument that you can use for this.
Combined with `order(c1)` so that the "first" element will also be the min of `c1` for each `name`

```
library(data.table)
x <- data.table(x, key=name)
y <- data.table(y, key=name)

xy <- merge(x, y, all=TRUE)

unique(xy[order(c1)], by="name")
#    name  c1 c2
# 1:  foo 0.1  y
# 2:  bar 0.2  w
# 3:  qux 0.8  z
```